# Show that the following functions are measurable for extented real numbers.

Tags: measure-theory, functions, measurable-functions

$f$,$g$ : $\Omega$ $\rightarrow$ [-$\infty$,$\infty$] measurable functions.

Show that the following functions are measurable:
1) $f$ $\cdot$ $g$ 
2) max{f,g}
3) $f^+$
4) $f^-$
5) |$f$|
6) $\alpha$ $\cdot$ $f$ + $\beta$ $\cdot$ $g$ for $\alpha$,$\beta$ $\in$ [-$\infty$, $\infty$ ]
I was able to show that the functions are measurable, but only for $\mathbb{R}$, not for the extented real numbers.

We don't know that:
$f$ + $g$, $\alpha$ $\cdot$ $f$are measurable.
We know that: continuous functions, composition are measurable. But I don't know if this helps for my problem.

Thank you for your reply.